Implementation of Formula Seems off
I am a researcher trying to use python to translate a formula for scoring liver cirrhosis called MELD and MELDNa. Would someone please double check my implementation of the formula into python?
So this is the formula:
MELD = 1.33 (if female) + [4.56 x loge(bilirubin)] + [0.82 x (137 – sodium)] – [0.24 x (137 – sodium) x loge(bilirubin)] + [9.09 x loge(INR)] + [11.14 x loge(creatinine)] + [1.85 x (3.5 – albumin)] – [1.83 x (3.5 – albumin) x loge(creatinine)] + 6

MELD-Na = MELD + 1.32 x (137-Na) – [0.033 x MELD x (137-Na)]

import pandas as pd
import math

def calculate_meld(bilirubin, sodium, INR, creatinine, albumin, Sex):
    if bilirubin <= 0 or sodium <= 0 or INR <= 0 or creatinine <= 0:
        return None  # Return None if any of the required parameters are non-positive
    
    if Sex.lower() == 'female':
        meld_score = (1.33 +
                      4.56 * math.log(bilirubin) + 
                      0.82 * (137 - sodium) - 
                      0.24 * (137 - sodium) * math.log(bilirubin) + 
                      9.09 * math.log(INR) + 
                      11.14 * math.log(creatinine) + 
                      1.85 * (3.5 - albumin) - 
                      1.83 * (3.5 - albumin) - 
                      1.83 * (3.5 - albumin) * math.log(creatinine) + 
                      6)
    else:
        meld_score = (4.56 * math.log(bilirubin) + 
                      0.82 * (137 - sodium) - 
                      0.24 * (137 - sodium) * math.log(bilirubin) + 
                      9.09 * math.log(INR) + 
                      11.14 * math.log(creatinine) + 
                      1.85 * (3.5 - albumin) - 
                      1.83 * (3.5 - albumin) - 
                      1.83 * (3.5 - albumin) * math.log(creatinine) + 
                      6)
    
    meld_score = round(meld_score)
    meld_score = max(6, min(meld_score, 40))  # Limiting the MELD score between 6 and 40
    return meld_score

def calculate_meld_na(meld, sodium):
    if meld is None:
        return None  # Return None if MELD score is None
    
    meld_na_score = meld + 1.32 * (137 - sodium) - 0.033 * meld * (137 - sodium)
    
    meld_na_score = round(meld_na_score)
    meld_na_score = max(6, min(meld_na_score, 40))  # Limiting the MELD-Na score between 6 and 40
    return meld_na_score

# Load data from Excel file
data = pd.read_excel('ICC NSQIP Data.xlsx')

# Drop rows with missing data
data.dropna(subset=['Total Bilirubin', 'Serum Sodium', 'INR', 'Serum Creatinine', 'Albumin', 'Sex'], inplace=True)

# Extract relevant columns
bilirubin = data['Total Bilirubin']
sodium = data['Serum Sodium']
INR = data['INR']
creatinine = data['Serum Creatinine']
albumin = data['Albumin']
Sex = data['Sex']

# Calculate MELD and MELD-Na scores
meld_scores = [calculate_meld(b, s, i, c, a, g) for b, s, i, c, a, g in zip(bilirubin, sodium, INR, creatinine, albumin, Sex)]
meld_scores = [score if score is not None else 0 for score in meld_scores]  # Replace None with 0

meld_na_scores = [calculate_meld_na(m, s) for m, s in zip(meld_scores, sodium)]

# Add MELD and MELD-Na scores to the DataFrame
data['MELD Score'] = meld_scores
data['MELD-Na Score'] = meld_na_scores

# Save the updated DataFrame to a new Excel file
data.to_excel('liver_data_updated_2.xlsx', index=False)

It runs and gives us data, but it's off for several rows of data versus when we manually calculate

When you say it is off for several rows of data, does that mean you get the correct results for some rows as well?

I'd say it's mostly not correct when we spot checked it, it could be a fluke that certain rows matched the online calculator. We're using the documentation provided for that online calculator too, so the same formulas are being used.

well if some results are correct, I would rule out that it is a calculation issue. If you want a fix for the issue please provide your input data and expected output results so that we can test it

take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

I suspect there is an error in how you handle None in
meld_scores = [score if score is not None else 0 for score in meld_scores]  # Replace None with 0

Here is a updated version of your code where I changed this and improved you function calculate_meld(). Not having your data, I created a sample dataframe. Replace that part with data = pd.read_excel('ICC NSQIP Data.xlsx') when you test the code
import pandas as pd
import math

def calculate_meld(bilirubin, sodium, INR, creatinine, albumin, Sex):
    if bilirubin <= 0 or sodium <= 0 or INR <= 0 or creatinine <= 0 or albumin <= 0:
        return None  
    
    female_adjustment = 1.33 if Sex.lower() == 'female' else 0
    
    meld_score = (female_adjustment +
                  4.56 * math.log(bilirubin) + 
                  0.82 * (137 - sodium) - 
                  0.24 * (137 - sodium) * math.log(bilirubin) + 
                  9.09 * math.log(INR) + 
                  11.14 * math.log(creatinine) + 
                  1.85 * (3.5 - albumin) - 
                  1.83 * (3.5 - albumin) * math.log(creatinine) + 
                  6)
    
    meld_score = round(meld_score)
    meld_score = max(6, min(meld_score, 40)) 
    return meld_score

def calculate_meld_na(meld, sodium):
    if meld is None:
        return None  
    
    meld_na_score = meld + 1.32 * (137 - sodium) - 0.033 * meld * (137 - sodium)
    meld_na_score = round(meld_na_score)
    meld_na_score = max(6, min(meld_na_score, 40)) 
    return meld_na_score

data = {
    'Total Bilirubin': [1.2, 2.5, 0.8, 1.0, 1.7],
    'Serum Sodium': [135, 140, 138, 136, 134],
    'INR': [1.1, 1.5, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4],
    'Serum Creatinine': [1.0, 1.8, 0.9, 1.1, 1.3],
    'Albumin': [3.2, 3.6, 3.0, 3.1, 3.4],
    'Sex': ['male', 'female', 'male', 'female', 'male']
}

data = pd.DataFrame(data)


data.dropna(subset=['Total Bilirubin', 'Serum Sodium', 'INR', 'Serum Creatinine', 'Albumin', 'Sex'], inplace=True)

bilirubin = data['Total Bilirubin']
sodium = data['Serum Sodium']
INR = data['INR']
creatinine = data['Serum Creatinine']
albumin = data['Albumin']
Sex = data['Sex']

meld_scores = [calculate_meld(b, s, i, c, a, g) for b, s, i, c, a, g in zip(bilirubin, sodium, INR, creatinine, albumin, Sex)]
meld_na_scores = [calculate_meld_na(m, s) for m, s in zip(meld_scores, sodium)]

data['MELD Score'] = meld_scores
data['MELD-Na Score'] = meld_na_scores

data.to_excel('liver_data_updated_2.xlsx', index=False)

print(data)


For the sample data it returns:
   Total Bilirubin  Serum Sodium  INR  Serum Creatinine  Albumin     Sex  \
0              1.2           135  1.1               1.0      3.2    male   
1              2.5           140  1.5               1.8      3.6  female   
2              0.8           138  1.2               0.9      3.0    male   
3              1.0           136  1.3               1.1      3.1  female   
4              1.7           134  1.4               1.3      3.4    male   

   MELD Score  MELD-Na Score  
0          10             12  
1          20             18  
2           6              6  
3          12             13  
4          17             19  

